# how to store and retrieve data in angular js?

Tags: jquery, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

can you please tell me how to store data permantly (example local storage)and retrieve data .I want to store data so that I get again .I am doing client side programing ? I google it it say there is persistance.js will do that ..can we use that ?I am try to make a simple example to store data but not able to that .I want to save list of name of student and class.
here is my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/cLTIJfETGYENQyEdsu94?p=preview

```
 // Code goes here
    var app = angular.module('appstart', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      //  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'tem.html',
          controller: 'ctrl'
        })


      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
    });

    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

      $scope.students = [];

      $scope.add = function() {

        $scope.students.push({
          inputName : angular.copy($scope.inputName),
          inputclass : angular.copy($scope.inputclass)
        });

        $scope.inputclass='';
        $scope.inputName='';
        }

    }
    );
```

thanks

Comment: Angular or not, the principle is the same: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @Shomz thanks for update ..can you please check my plunker .and add only single entry.rest think I will do own.I will just want on add it add on data base

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: I am making desktop application using client side language, jquery, angular.js, HTML5

Comment: which type of dB angular support I need to just add, delete , edit entries

Comment: Is your db at a server? Or on the client?

Comment: on client side ..I just save data locally .But i don't want to use local storage

Comment: Ah, so you **don't** want to use localStorage.

Comment: yes..because i need to create table with id, name and class entry.as ocal storage is usd for smal data..

Comment: hi all is this possible..?

Comment: Still confused of why you don't want to use localStorage.

Comment: @runTarm local storage have only limit of 5 MB data maximu.I need add more data mean I want to get or store data using query

Comment: I need to create table as we do in webworks and implement edit, delete ,add function

Comment: any body have more question .Please give suggestion for creating DB in client side using angular

Comment: Any solution to create DB on client side

Comment: how are you going to create a desktop app using angularjs, jquery, and HTML5? regarding DB you need to install DB server on the client machine (and on each client machine), then install management tool to manage your database (create table, etc.)

Comment: @Arief i need to creat like this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: can we make like that As I given ?

Comment: You will also run into a space limitation with the WebSql, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/

Comment: @but I need to make same with angular..can you please help

Comment: mean create table and have two columns and insert that after presing add

Answer (score 0):

you can grab angular-local-storage here: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

That makes it easy to use the browser localstorage, I've updated your plunker with an example of use: http://plnkr.co/edit/W06UnVysGx0FMVnITMZD

```
app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope','localStorageService', function($scope, localStorageService) {

  $scope.students = [];

  $scope.add = function() {

    $scope.students.push({
      inputName : angular.copy($scope.inputName),
      inputclass : angular.copy($scope.inputclass)
    });

    $scope.inputclass='';
    $scope.inputName='';
  }

  $scope.loadFromStorage = function(){
    $scope.students = localStorageService.get('studentsList');
    if($scope.students == null)
      $scope.students = [];
  }

  $scope.saveToStorage = function(){
    localStorageService.set('studentsList', $scope.students);
  }

}]);
```

Keep in mind that this does not persist your data across the web, if you want to do that, you should setup a webserver from which you can post and get the data.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks ...you use localstorage ..i don't want to use that .I want to create table

Comment: In that table I will give coloumn name :"id" ,"name","classname"

Comment: Oh in that case you must have an endpoint setup in a webserver, so you can use the $http service to post and get the data. The webserver is the one responsible for storing the data in a database, angular itself can't do it.

Comment: we cann't create table ..but some one told me using websql may be we can create.or sqlite

Comment: Hmm well I do not have a complete understanding of WebSql, but with a quick research I found out that it uses localstorage as well, and also that it seems to be discontinued: http://csimms.botonomy.com/2011/05/html5-storage-wars-localstorage-vs-indexeddb-vs-web-sql.html

Comment: I think your code will work fine without angular-local-storage.js jsbecause browser will store it local storage

Comment: mean there is local storage of web browser..it save in that

Comment: angular-local-storage.js facilitates the usage of the browser's local storage

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have many choices to keep data persistent and to store it, here those that i know:

```
1 - localStorage or sessionStorage or IndexedDB

2 - cookie if your data is < 4kb (cookie max size)

3 - server side (mysql, redis, mongo and noSQL,json or other extension files etc)

4 - client side (json file or whatever file format you want/can develop)
```

Obviously some of these features are not always suppoerted, check here the one you preferr to support or not [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)

Just choose the one that fits your needs and create a dataFactory to store, delete, retrieve data :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a database. Web-storage is only for temporary things.

If you have a backend, you can use a service and `$http` to create a CRUD application.

You use Angular to send data to the backend which does the persistence.