# how to send parameter value in second view in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

can you please tell me how to display the value of parameter on second view ?Actually I make a form  in which there is two field : name and class .when user press(after filling fields) add it generate a row below  .on click I get the value of name and class Now I want to show that name and value on next page .can we show this ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/NSZufLOX7bt52S3fdAXo?p=preview

```
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope',"$location",function(s,$location){
    s.students = [];

    s.add = function() {

        s.students.push({
            inputName : angular.copy(s.inputName),
            inputclass : angular.copy(s.inputclass)
        });

        s.inputclass='';
        s.inputName='';
    }
    s.getListClick=function(name,className){
        alert(name+":"+className);
        $location.path('/navigation')

    }

}])
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean you have two parameters which you want to send them to your next page ?

Comment: If so , you can use $routeParams ,

Comment: yes ..exactly .your are right

Comment: i think there is way to pass through controller ?

Comment: when data is pass between two controller ? can you change plunker

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this
1- $location.search({}) -> with search parameters
2- with route params
3 - with defining a new factory

Comment: @xe4me can you please give example on plunker ..thanks.please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this using `$routeParams`, but if you want to share data between multiple controllers then a common way to do this is using a service that exposes getters and setters to each controller it is injected into.

```
app.factory('Data', function(){
    var data =
        {
            name: '',
            class: ''
        };

    return {
        getName: function () {
            return data.name;
        },
        setName: function (name) {
            data.name = name;
        },
        getClass: function () {
            return data.class;
        },
        setClass: function (klass) {
            //class is reserved word :)
            data.class = klass;
        },
    };
});
```

And then to share the data:

```
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope',"$location","Data",function(s,$location,Data){
    s.students = [];

    s.add = function() {

        s.students.push({
            inputName : angular.copy(s.inputName),
            inputclass : angular.copy(s.inputclass)
        });

        Data.setName(s.inputName);
        Data.setClass(s.inputclass);

        s.inputclass='';
        s.inputName='';
    }
    s.getListClick=function(name,className){
        alert(name+":"+className);
        $location.path('/navigation')

    }

}]);

app.controller("secondCtrl",['$scope',"Data",function(s,Data){
    s.name = Data.getName();
    s.class = Data.getClass();
}]);
```

Then in each controller you can either check for updates to the data by using the getters, or use `$watch` to check for changes automatically:

```
s.$watch(function () { return Data.getName(); }, function (newVal) {
    if (newValue) {
      s.name = newVal;
    }
});
```

Here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/vm1wrahKYOLhvsKKyXj2?p=preview

EDIT:

Here's how to pass parameters between views using `ngRoute` and `$routeParams` (using the code you provided):

```
  $routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'tem.html',
    controller: 'ctrl'
  })
  .when('/navigation/:name', {
    templateUrl: 'second.html',
    controller: 'secondCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
```

And then in the controller you can use:

```
$location.path('/navigation/' + name);
```

And to read in the `$routeParams`:

```
app.controller("secondCtrl",['$scope',"$routeParams",function(s,routeParams){
  s.name = routeParams.name;
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kYwIEsBqSrJRJf37ZPI8?p=preview

Comment: thanks ..I am looking for same ..actually some one told me using routparam and search param also do that..can you also use both term

Comment: can you please explain how we can achieve using route param

Comment: Sure let me set up a plunkr, one second.

Comment: you have any idea of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094512/how-to-store-and-retrieve-data-in-anguar-js?noredirect=1#comment39050377_25094512

Comment: mean I need to save data in websql.so that I will get back when I get back..I need to store data using websql

Comment: I'll take a look at the other question and see if I can help :)